# some arguments can be changed in method, but some not in java

Tags: java

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean flag=false;
        char[] c=new char[5];
        c[0]='e';
        read(flag, c);

        System.out.println(c[0]);
        System.out.println(flag);
    }

   public static void read(boolean flag, char[] c){
        flag=true;
        c[0]='a';
   }
}
```

In the above code, I find an interesting problem: the `char[] c` has been changed and print the result right, but the boolean flag has not been changed! I do not know how this happened? 
and now, I want to change the flag too, how this can be done?
thanks for your help!

Comment: the difference is that one parameter is a reference parameter (the array) and one is a primitive. Since Java method parameters are pass by value only, the primitive cannot be changed in the method, nor can the reference *to the parameter* be changed, but the contents of the referred to object can be changed. Think of the array like passing in an egg crate. You can't change the egg crate due to "pass by value", but you can change the eggs held by the crate.

Comment: I've always found [this](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) to be a good writeup for understanding java parameter passing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `boolean` is passed by value.  If you change it in the `read` method, then that only changes the local copy, not the outside value.

However, the *reference* to `c` is passed by value, effectively making the array referred to by `c` passed by reference.  So, changing an element of `c` here does affect the outside array.

Comment: +1 for being correct and mentioning both are passed by value, you almost had me at "The boolean is passed by value" but I saw you mentioned that " the reference to c is passed by value".

Comment: yes, you are right! this case is similar to the parameters passed in C language. but in C, I can use &flag as parameter and *flag=true, which can change the flag. how can I do this in JAVA ? Do you have a good method?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in how Java handles arrays and primitives.

## Arrays

Java handles arrays (and other objects, too) as reference types. That means that Java doesn't give the method the array itself. Rather, the method receives a number (a **reference**) that tells it where the array is stored.

Thus, any method receiving an array is not taking a copy of the array; it is changing the original array. If you modify an object by a) calling a method on an object or b) subscripting `[]` an array, it will change the original.

## Primitives (`boolean`, etc.)

Primitives work differently from arrays. Methods do not receive references to primitives; they receive copies of the primitives. This is because primitives are simpler than objects, and the performance loss associated with copying objects does not apply to the maximum about 8 bytes of a primitive.

Thus, you are recieving a copy of the boolean you pass to the method. Therefore, changing the copy will not affect the original.

Hope this helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You do different things with the two argument. You simply assign to the boolean, which only changes your copy of the boolean value.

On the other hand, you use your copy of the array reference argument to modify the array it points to. If, instead, you had done a simple assignment: `c = null;` or `c = new char[30];` you would have changed your copy of the argument, but not affected the caller's copy, just like the boolean.

Of course, there is a lot more you can do with a reference expression than with a boolean expression.